# How to randomly add class to "td" of table with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, match

I am trying to build a seat booking app.

I have a HTML table as the below picture.

[image]

HTML codes

```
<table class="responsive-table bordered booking-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>A1</td>
                            <td>A2</td>
                            <td>A3</td>
                            <td>A4</td>
                            <td>A5</td>
                            <td>A6</td>
                            <td>A7</td>
                            <td>A8</td>
                            <td>A9</td>
                            <td>A10</td>
                            <td>A11</td>
                            <td>A12</td>
                            <td>A13</td>
                            <td>A14</td>
                            <td>A15</td>
                            <td>A16</td>
                            <td>A17</td>
                            <td>A18</td>
                            <td>A19</td>
                            <td>A20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>B1</td>
                            <td>B2</td>
                            <td>B3</td>
                            <td>B4</td>
                            <td>B5</td>
                            <td>B6</td>
                            <td>B7</td>
                            <td>B8</td>
                            <td>B9</td>
                            <td>B10</td>
                            <td>B11</td>
                            <td>B12</td>
                            <td>B13</td>
                            <td>B14</td>
                            <td>B15</td>
                            <td>B16</td>
                            <td>B17</td>
                            <td>B18</td>
                            <td>B19</td>
                            <td>B20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>C1</td>
                            <td>C2</td>
                            <td>C3</td>
                            <td>C4</td>
                            <td>C5</td>
                            <td>C6</td>
                            <td>C7</td>
                            <td>C8</td>
                            <td>C9</td>
                            <td>C10</td>
                            <td>C11</td>
                            <td>C12</td>
                            <td>C13</td>
                            <td>C14</td>
                            <td>C15</td>
                            <td>C16</td>
                            <td>C17</td>
                            <td>C18</td>
                            <td>C19</td>
                            <td>C20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>D1</td>
                            <td>D2</td>
                            <td>D3</td>
                            <td>D4</td>
                            <td>D5</td>
                            <td>D6</td>
                            <td>D7</td>
                            <td>D8</td>
                            <td>D9</td>
                            <td>D10</td>
                            <td>D11</td>
                            <td>D12</td>
                            <td>D13</td>
                            <td>D14</td>
                            <td>D15</td>
                            <td>D16</td>
                            <td>D17</td>
                            <td>D18</td>
                            <td>D19</td>
                            <td>D20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>E1</td>
                            <td>E2</td>
                            <td>E3</td>
                            <td>E4</td>
                            <td>E5</td>
                            <td>E6</td>
                            <td>E7</td>
                            <td>E8</td>
                            <td>E9</td>
                            <td>E10</td>
                            <td>E11</td>
                            <td>E12</td>
                            <td>E13</td>
                            <td>E14</td>
                            <td>E15</td>
                            <td>E16</td>
                            <td>E17</td>
                            <td>E18</td>
                            <td>E19</td>
                            <td>E20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>F1</td>
                            <td>F2</td>
                            <td>F3</td>
                            <td>F4</td>
                            <td>F5</td>
                            <td>F6</td>
                            <td>F7</td>
                            <td>F8</td>
                            <td>F9</td>
                            <td>F10</td>
                            <td>F11</td>
                            <td>F12</td>
                            <td>F13</td>
                            <td>F14</td>
                            <td>F15</td>
                            <td>F16</td>
                            <td>F17</td>
                            <td>F18</td>
                            <td>F19</td>
                            <td>F20</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And I have the seat numbers which are booked by users and randomly stored as an array.

e.g

```
var booked_seats = ["A2", "A6", "B7", "B8", "B12", "D1", "D7", "D8"];
```

What I want to do is I want to highlight the table's **td** boxes.

For instance, if the array data includes the seat number **A2**, it will highlight the **A2** box with a class named "highlight".

e.g something like this

```
if (array_data_number == booking_table_number){
   $('table>tbody>tr>td').addClass('highlight'); 
}
```

How can I achieve it with Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple click event will do the trick.

```
$("td").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("highlight")
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tvaudq71/

Or pre-select from array

```
var booked_seats = ["A2", "A6", "B7", "B8", "B12", "D1", "D7", "D8"];   

$(".bordered").find("td").each(function(){

   if(booked_seats.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1)
   {
       $(this).addClass("highlight");
   }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tvaudq71/2/

Comment: In this case, it has to be highlighted since the page is loaded. so it doesn't work with click event. Btw, Thanks for sharing @Adriani6

Comment: @Taplar Correct, my bad. copy & paste wrongly from my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//find all the td
$('.booking-table td').filter(function(){
  //return those that have their text in the booked seats
  return booked_seats.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
}).addClass('highlight'); //add the class to all the tds matched
```